# Cannot Compile OpenCV 2.4.5 with VS 2013 RTM

Tags: visual-c++, opencv, visual-studio-2013

Has anyone had any luck compiling openCV with VS 2013 RTM? I have tried and get a bunch of "min doesn't belong to namespace std" "max doesn't belong to namespace std" in the IlmImf module, and opencv_features2d doesn't compile with the following error:

**opencv\modules\core\include\opencv2/core/core.hpp(4512): fatal error C1075: end of file found before the left brace '{' at '......\modules\features2d\src\features2d_init.cpp(187)' was matched**

Since the latest CMake UI doesn't yet support building with 2013 (at least from the UI and I'm a noob), my process was configuring CMake for 2012, and then opening the generated solution with 2013 and upgrading the compiler to vc12.

I was able to get past the min/max errors by adding header includes for  in the 'offending' files, but I am stumped by the full error I posted above.

Thanks

**Update:**

The accepted answer provides what is necessary to compile OpenCV in 32-bit debug and release, and 64-bit debug, but now the compiler fails to compile 64-bit release due to an internal compiler error. This is likely the compiler's fault at this point, but the answer is still solves many problems.

**Update 2:**
So the 64-bit issue turned out to be a bug in the auto-vectorizer. Here is the corresponding workaround.

> Hi, thanks for the great bug report. I confirm this is a bug in the compiler optimizer. We will fix it in a future release.
>
> If you need a source code workaround, please turn the vectorizer off on the loop inside **computeOrbDescriptor**:
>
> **#pragma loop(no_vector)**
>
> **for (int i = 0; i < dsize; ++i)**
>
> **{**
>
> ```
>    **...**
> ```
>
> That lets me build orb.cpp & stardetector.cpp.
>
> If this issue is severe, causing critical business situations or blocking your product development or deployment, please go to http://support.microsoft.com or call 1-800-MICROSOFT for assistance. For Microsoft premier customers, please contact your administrator, your Technical Account Manager, or your Microsoft premier account representative.
>
> I am closing this MSConnect item. Feel free to respond if you need anything else.
>
> Thanks,
>
> Eric Brumer - Microsoft Visual C++ Team

The connect bug can be found [here](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/804934/the-compiler-crashes-when-compiling-opencv-for-release-x64). Unfortunately the real fix for this is postponed until a later date.

Comment: Did you had any progress so far?

Comment: Not yet. I haven't decided whether this is an OpenCV issue or a vc12 issue. I am leaning towards the latter since I have looked at the offending code and it seems fine to me.

Comment: Any luck on the second issue? I'm having the same with VS2013.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've managed to compile OpenCV 2.4.6 on VS2013 RC, but initially it had the same errors as in question.
I've opened VS solution and fixed all error in two steps:

1) Replaced (Ctrl+H)

```
#include \<string\>
```

to

```
#include <algorithm>\n#include <string>
```

in *entire solution* (be sure to enable RegExp in replace dialog)

2) In "modules/opencv_features2d/Src/features2d_init.cpp" changed line 184 to:

```
obj.info()->addParam(obj, "detector", (Ptr<Algorithm>&) obj.detector);
```

(search for "GridAdaptedFeatureDetector" in this file for other OpenCV versions)

Comment: Have you been successful in compiling it in release? What you did definitely works for debug, but in release I get an internal compiler error when compiling orb.cpp in features2d.

Comment: That is strange, because I've successfully compiled it in both configurations. However, I had internal compiler error on another project under VS2013RC; reinstallation of VS helped me that time.

Comment: It's possible. The RTM just got released, so I will try it again. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I was unsuccessful with the RTM too. Re-install didn't help :/

Comment: @akazahov Ok, so I am guessing that you compiled it for 32-bit release? I just tried 32-bit and that worked fine, but the compiler crashes when compiling 64-bit release.

Comment: This answer worked for me too, though I was stuck with Visual Studio 2012 on Windows 8. It may be worth note that [the latest version of features2d_init.cpp](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/features2d/src/features2d_init.cpp) has that line replaced with `obj.info()->addParam<FeatureDetector>(obj, "detector", obj.detector, false, 0, 0);`

Answer (score 4):

For the first issue:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2013/06/28/c-11-14-stl-features-fixes-and-breaking-changes-in-vs-2013.aspx

It is explicitly called out:

- You must `#include <algorithm>` when calling std::min() or std::max().

Before due to the internal implementation of the VC++ libraries `<string>` would pull in these functions.

Comment: Thanks for the documentation link for the first problem

Answer (score 3):

Please see http://code.opencv.org/issues/3273 for more information on the internal compiler error issue.