# Compile a project in VS2013 with static linking to OpenCV (C++)

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2013

Whenever I try to compile my project in Visual Studio 2013, with the additional library directory set to $(OPENCV_DIR)\staticlib, I get the following error, repeated 41 times across different OpenCV files:

`error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_MSC_VER': value '1700' doesn't match value '1800' in main.obj`

How would I go about fixing this? I'm assuming it's to do with compiler versions, but I don't know how to get it fixed.

My OPENCV_DIR is set to `C:\opencv\build\x86\vc11`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard library implementation is not compatible across different versions of Visual Studio and it looks like you have a version of OpenCV compiled with VS2012 that you're trying to link with VS2013.

[MSDN describes the situation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531344%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in the "Breaking Changes" for Visual C++ in VS2012 although it's not specifically mentioned yet for VS2013. Quoting from that page:

[image: msdn]

To overcome this, you will need to rebuild OpenCV static libraries using VS2013 first, then try linking with your VS2013 application.

Comment: Ah, OK. How would I build it with VS2013? The OpenCV installer guide recommends using CMake, and that only comes with config options up to VS2012.

Comment: @dantdj What I would do is to get a VS2012 solution that builds ok, then just open that with VS2013 and let it upgrade.

Comment: So I need to get VS2012 installed? Ah, joy... xD

Comment: @dantdj not necessarily, you can always use CMake to generate a VS2012 solution then open with VS2013 and go from there. There is [a related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17409956/2065121) about building OpenCV with VS2013 that may be useful.

Comment: Ah, OK, thank you. I'll give that a go and post any problems I get here.

Comment: Well, everything built. However, now I'm getting this linker error: `error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_filesystem-vc120-mt-sgd-1_55.lib'` which I'm not really sure how to fix. Any ideas?