# cmake rebuild opencv3 no lib in staticlib

Tags: c++, opencv

When I rebuild opencv3 by cmake, and try to generate project by visual 2017 there was only one file in staticlib which I generated. just ippicvmt.lib

my step is like this
open cmake --> choice source folder and target folder --> configure --> configure --> open "OpenCV.sln" by vs2017 --> run install.

Comment: Were there any errors in the build process?

Comment: there is no any error.in cmake step , i did't choice test and perf_test. there is no any error.i will try vs2015 now.

Comment: What about the Visual Studio step?

Comment: no any error too..don't know why....why there was only one lib..no any error.....vs 2015 is not ok. i resaerch a lot of document and blog, they have almost the same steps.I completely follow other people's blog's step.thank u .u answer is a comfort for me.actually my purpose is just publish my exe with static compilation without .dll, but i get an error, i know the opencv 3.0 not support vs (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20313657/compile-a-project-in-vs2013-with-static-linking-to-opencv-c)i have to rebuild it.

Comment: i guess maybe the lower vs can solve this, but i want to try to rebuild it ..

Comment: hey man,i solve this.in cmake step.deselect the build_share_library.then the staticlib will be generated.and i publish my exe successfully .